# Unable to get text/data from within a <div class> using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning how to scrape data from websites using BeautifulSoup. In this particular case I'm trying to get data from `url = 'https://www.embalses.net/estacion-meteorologica-320.html'` and extract the rainfall from the last hours/day.

The information I want is in `<div class="ResultadoInf">`, to be precise: `<div class="ResultadoInf"> **0.0 mm**</div>`.

I am able to find the part of the page that contains all `ResultadoInf` with `rain_container = html_soup.find_all('div', class_="ResultadoInf")`. Then I manage to find the part that contains the specific data that I have, but somehow I can not obtain *just* the data I need, i.e. `0.0 mm`.

How can I extract that part of the code from the `div class`? Many thanks!

Comment: You can get text part of element via `.get_text()`, since find_all returns all elements it finds in a list, for your case that should be `rain_container[0].get_text()`. Please read the documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Comment: Thanks! It works. I saw the ´.text´ option, but did not manage to get it to work. Now it does!